# Webcam on XPS M1530 doesn't work with 12.04

Tags: drivers, hardware, webcam

I have a Dell XPS M1530 that originally came with Ubuntu (back in 2006 or so). The Webcam has always worked out of the box in Cheese, Skype, etc. I don't use it regularly, but I had tested it before. I recently tried it after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm getting a black screen in every application I try. (The blue webcam light does go on, I just don't get any video.)

Here's what I've figured out:

- This is my webcam as reported by `lsusb`: `Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam`
- It should be supported by the UVC drivers: http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices
- In all applications tested, the blue light turns on but the video is black.
- Cheese output:

> ```
> libv4l2: error got 4 consecutive frame decode errors, last error: v4l-convert: 
> libjpeg error: End Of Image
> libv4l2: error got 4 consecutive frame decode errors, last error: v4l-convert: libjpeg error: End Of Image
> libv4l2: error got 4 consecutive frame decode errors, last error: v4l-convert: libjpeg error: End Of Image
> libv4l2: error got 4 consecutive frame decode errors, last error: v4l-convert: libjpeg error: End Of Image
> libv4l2: error got 4 consecutive frame decode errors, last error: v4l-convert: libjpeg error: End Of Image
> ```

- guvcview output:

> ```
> guvcview 1.5.3
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
> ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
> ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
> ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
> ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
> Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
> Cannot connect to server socket
> jack server is not running or cannot be started
> video device: /dev/video0 
> Init. Laptop Integrated Webcam (location: usb-0000:00:1a.0-1)
> { pixelformat = 'MJPG', description = 'MJPEG' }
> { discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
>   Time interval between frame: 2/15, 
> { pixelformat = 'RGB3', description = 'RGB3' }
> { discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
>   Time interval between frame: 2/15, 
> { pixelformat = 'BGR3', description = 'BGR3' }
> { discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
>   Time interval between frame: 2/15, 
> { pixelformat = 'YU12', description = 'YU12' }
> { discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
>   Time interval between frame: 2/15, 
> { pixelformat = 'YV12', description = 'YV12' }
> { discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
>   Time interval between frame: 2/15, 
> vid:05a9 
> pid:2640 
> driver:uvcvideo
> checking format: 1196444237
> VIDIOC_G_COMP:: Invalid argument
>    compression control not supported
> fps is set to 2/15
> drawing controls
>
> fps is set to 2/15
> no codec detected for H264
> no codec detected for MP3 - (lavc)
> Checking video mode 160x120@32bpp : OK 
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
> Ignoring empty buffer ...
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
> Ignoring empty buffer ...
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
> Ignoring empty buffer ...
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
> Ignoring empty buffer ...
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
>  Could not grab image (select timeout): Resource temporarily unavailable
> ```

- Skype output (one error appeared each time I disabled video. No error when enabling video, but, of course, just a black screen and blue light.

> ```
> $ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
> libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: Invalid argument
> libv4l2: error allocating conversion buffer
> libv4l2: error allocating conversion buffer
> libv4l2: error allocating conversion buffer
> libv4l2: error allocating conversion buffer
> ```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have the exact same laptop (typing from it right now). Using Ubuntu 12.04 the webcam works perfectly without installing/uninstalling any package (cheese, skype, google+,...etc). Can you boot your laptop from a fresh ubuntu live USB or CD and test the camera with cheese? It might be some damaged library or a hardware issue, but that way we can tell either way.

Comment: Just did a fresh install this morning, actually.

Comment: in your question it says you did an upgrade. Fresh install or upgrade from 11.10? There could be some corrupted packages if you did the later, or even during a clean install. I would check with the live USB just to be sure.

Comment: I had been upgrading since 7.10 or something, but I was afraid that was teh issue. So this morning I reformatted and did a fresh install of 12.04 from CD. Still doesn't work. I'm beginning to wonder if this is a hardware problem. I think I'm gonna open it up and check the cable.

Comment: is a possibility. But before you do that make sure you check the camera booting from the live CD, just to rule out package corruption during install.

Comment: So I opened it up and disconnected and reconnected the ribbon cable on the motherboard side. After doing that, I booted and opened Cheese. Cheese displayed a frozen picture from the webcam, but then turned black again. When I opened uvcview it said there was no webcam connected. I rebooted again and now it's back to exactly the same thing as before (black screen, blue light, uvcview message is gone).

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!